# Google map error list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the `phone number` but they show me the error that your `list must be integer not a web element` I Have try different approches but they will show  me these error this is the link https://www.google.com/maps/search/dentist+uk/@31.4820415,74.2444157,12z/data=!3m1!4b1

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

data=[]
def supplyvan_scraper():
    with chrome_driver as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        URL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/dentist+uk/@31.5688259,74.2388013,12z/data=!3m1!4b1'
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)
        page_links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="hfpxzc"]')]

        # visit all the links
        for link in page_links:
            wev={}
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(2)
            link=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='RcCsl fVHpi w4vB1d NOE9ve M0S7ae AG25L']")
            for i in link:
                if '+' in link[i].get():
                    phone=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Io6YTe fontBodyMedium']").text
                    print(phone)


            time.sleep(2)
supplyvan_scraper()
```

Show error in these line:

```
if '+' in link[i]:
```

[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: `for i in link:` doesn't means `for i in range(len(link)):`. If you use `for i in link:` then you have to use `i.get()` instead of `link[i].get()`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\ScriptScraping\script.text\scr.py", line 41, in <module>
    supplyvan_scraper()
  File "e:\ScriptScraping\script.text\scr.py", line 35, in supplyvan_scraper
    if '+' in link[i].get():
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: maybe you need `.text` instead of `.get()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to check the phone number and print it out easily

Phone number contains only `digits` and starting with a `+` sign
So you may use this pattern - `^\+.*\d$`

You can search all the text elements and find the number using this pattern

working code -

```
def google_map_scraper():
    with chrome_driver as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        URL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/dentist+uk/@31.5688259,74.2388013,12z/data=!3m1!4b1'
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)
        page_links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in
                      driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="hfpxzc"]')]

        # visit all the links
        for link in page_links:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(2)
            link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='RcCsl fVHpi w4vB1d NOE9ve M0S7ae AG25L']")
            for i in link:
                if re.search('^\+.*\d$', i.text): # find the phone number starting with + and containing only digits
                    phone_num = i.text
                    print(phone_num) # print the phone number

            time.sleep(2)


google_map_scraper()
```

Output -

```
+92 334 5555859
+92 42 35749000
+92 322 3368251
+92 333 4254716
....
....
```

Comment: brother they show me error  `re is not defined`

Comment: add `import re` in the top of your code

Comment: brother if also search find website  then  these condition will be fine  `elif  re.search('.com', i.text):
website=i.text`

Comment: you need to add more options ther could be .com or .pk  etc.,

Comment: `if re.search('.com|.pk|.dental', i.text)` add options like this

Comment: I run the code instead of printing the phone number, they will print the `[3328:13160:0605/211604.992:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1092)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader`

Comment: they will print these on every line

Comment: when I print website link they will provide me but when I print phone number instead of providing text they will give me these code on every line`[3328:13160:0605/211604.992:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1092)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader`

Comment: check this - https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=18016